# How to fetch data from database with django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to fetch data from django database.

I want to display all the data as divs with different titles, images and description.

views.py

```
from .models import Links

def all_links(request):
   links= Links.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'links.html',
   {'links' : links})
```

models.py

```
class Links(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
desc = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
link_redirect = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
img = models.ImageField(upload_to = None,height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

output file:

```
 {% for link in link_list %}

    <div class="links--flex flex">
        <div class="links--flex__link">
            <div class="link__img">
                <img src={% static '/img/links/Pexels.png' %} alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="link__title">
                <h2 class='colored'>{{link.title}}</h2>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="link__short">
                <p>{{link.desc}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    {% endfor %}
```

But nothing is showing. I can see data in my admin panel. I did try to follow few tutorials but it still seems like something is wrong. My app is connected to project.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a variable named `link_list` in your template, but the name of the variable you are passing into the view is `links`. Change it to this:

```
{% for link in links %}
```

Comment: Oh yea, i tried different names and forgot to change. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: But if i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/links i can see all items from database